# polymorphism in haskell: the compiler doesn't let my function be polymorphic

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write myself a configuration file system in Haskell, but I'm hitting my limits with the type system. I think I should look into RankNTypes and ExistentialTypes and I've tried a bit, but I could not make this work. Is it possible that it's not doable at all?

I tried to shorten the code as much as possible but this is what I have now:

```
module Main where

import Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Control.Monad (liftM)

type Conf = M.Map String String

data Setting a = Setting { name :: String, defaultValue :: a }

textStroke :: Setting (Double,Double,Double,Double)
textStroke = Setting "textStroke" (1, 0.5, 0, 1)

marginXFromWidth :: Setting Double
marginXFromWidth = Setting "marginXFromWidth" 0.025

readSetting :: (Read a) => Conf -> Setting a -> a
readSetting conf (Setting key defaultV) = fromMaybe defaultV $ liftM read (M.lookup key conf)

readConfFile :: IO Conf
readConfFile = return $ M.empty

main = do
    conf <- readConfFile
    -- let (a,b,c,d) = readSetting conf textStroke
    -- let margin = readSetting conf marginXFromWidth
    let getSetting = readSetting conf
    let (a,b,c,d) = getSetting textStroke
    let margin = getSetting marginXFromWidth
    putStrLn "OK"
```

a Setting contains the name of the setting and the default value, which will be used if another value is not provided by the config file.

So, with the two commented lines it works fine. But I'd like to save one parameter to the "readSetting" function and so I introduce that getSetting function, which just shares the same first parameter as readSetting, so I can save some typing: `getSetting <setting>` instead of `readSetting conf <setting>`.

Unfortunately I get this build error:

```
TestSettings.hs:29:33:
    Couldn't match type `Double'
                  with `(Double, Double, Double, Double)'
    Expected type: Setting (Double, Double, Double, Double)
      Actual type: Setting Double
    In the first argument of `getSetting', namely `marginXFromWidth'
    In the expression: getSetting marginXFromWidth
    In an equation for `margin': margin = getSetting marginXFromWidth
```

That's because the compiler would like to choose between Setting (Double, Double..) and Setting Double for the concrete type. It does not let me have getSetting be polymorphic. Well, that's my interpretation anyway.

As I said I played a bit with forall and things like that, but I got nowhere. The fact is, I don't master those concepts for now.

So much effort for one parameter less (but I read settings often), but I would really like to get this.

So, how could I get the effect I'd like to achieve, to save that parameter? Or is completely non-haskelly and I'm going in the wrong direction?

*EDIT:* thank you for the NoMonomorphismRestriction it does answer the question, however it turns out that I simplified my code too much.
Here is want I really wanted and that is not fixed by that language pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
module Main where

import Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Control.Monad (liftM)

type Conf = M.Map String String

data Setting a = Setting { name :: String, defaultValue :: a }

textStroke :: Setting (Double,Double,Double,Double)
textStroke = Setting "textStroke" (1, 0.5, 0, 1)

marginXFromWidth :: Setting Double
marginXFromWidth = Setting "marginXFromWidth" 0.025

readSetting :: (Read a) => Conf -> Setting a -> a
readSetting conf (Setting key defaultV) = fromMaybe defaultV $ liftM read (M.lookup key conf)

readConfFile :: (Read a) => IO (Conf, Setting a -> a)
readConfFile = liftM (\conf -> (conf, readSetting conf)) $ return M.empty

main = do
    (conf, getSetting) <- readConfFile
    -- let (a,b,c,d) = readSetting conf textStroke
    -- let margin = readSetting conf marginXFromWidth
    --let getSetting = readSetting conf
    let (a,b,c,d) = getSetting textStroke
    let margin = getSetting marginXFromWidth
    putStrLn "OK"
```

That still does not build... Sorry I should have put this version upfront.
The reason for returning the pair is that I want to offer to users of the library this helper out of the box, i don't want them to have to spell it themselves, much less if it means for them to enable a compiler extension.

Comment: As an aside, note that `fromMaybe x $ liftM read y` is more easily written as `maybe x read y`.

Comment: I don't have time to answer this fully now, but... You want to say `readConfFile :: IO (Conf, forall a. Read a => Setting a -> a)`. That signature requires the `ImpredicativeTypes` extension, which really isn't usable in the real world.  It requires too many type annotations. The standard workaround is using a `newtype` wrapper containing a polymorphic function using `RankNTypes`, so the newtype doesn't show the polymorphism externally.

Comment: Carl I'm pretty sure you have the solution, however I hope someone types the solution in full.. If noone does I'll try to do it myself but I know I won't have an easy time :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Answer to edited question

If you want to do that, you indeed need to use `RankNTypes`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Main where

import Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Control.Monad (liftM)

type Conf = M.Map String String

data Setting a = Setting { name :: String, defaultValue :: a }

newtype GetSetting = GetSetting (forall a. Read a => Setting a -> a)

textStroke :: Setting (Double,Double,Double,Double)
textStroke = Setting "textStroke" (1, 0.5, 0, 1)

marginXFromWidth :: Setting Double
marginXFromWidth = Setting "marginXFromWidth" 0.025

readSetting :: Read a => Conf -> Setting a -> a
readSetting conf (Setting key defaultV) = fromMaybe defaultV $ liftM read (M.lookup key conf)

readConfFile :: IO (Conf, GetSetting)
readConfFile = liftM (\conf -> (conf, GetSetting $ readSetting conf)) $ return M.empty

main = do
    (conf, GetSetting getSetting) <- readConfFile
    let (a,b,c,d) = getSetting textStroke
    let margin = getSetting marginXFromWidth
    putStrLn "OK"
```

You want `readConfFile` to return a function that works *for all* a (provided that a is an instance of Read). With `RankNTypes`, you could try to write `readConfFile :: IO (Conf, forall a. Read a => Setting a -> a)`, but that doesn't work because you cannot have types with `forall` inside them *as arguments to type constructors* (`forall a. Read a => Setting a -> a` is used as an argument to the type constructor `(,)`) (with `ImpredicativeTypes` you could, but `ImpredicativeTypes` destroys type-inference). This is the reason why I created a `newtype GetSetting` containing the function `getSetting :: forall a. Read a => Setting a -> a`.

---

#### Answer to original question

The reason for this is the so-called MonomorphismRestriction. It forces all local bindings (those introduced with let or where) to have a monomorphic type. Adding the following pragma to the very top of your file will disable the monomorphism restriction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

An alternative is to give an explicit type signature for `getSetting`, like this:

```
let getSetting :: Read a => Setting a -> a
    getSetting = readSetting conf
```

See the wiki for more information on the monomorphism restriction: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction

Comment: That is very helpful and 100% answers the question I asked. However when simplifying my code for posting, I simplified it too much and that affects the solution obviously. I now posted a second version which is closer to what I want to achieve and in that solution the pragma does not help...

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the solution. I wonder if users when I split this code, users of the library will have to use RankNTypes or it'll be only in my code, I think only in my code but I'll see when I try. I'll need to some time to be fluent with these concepts...